# Extremal poker: the most favored that a currently weakest hand can be

Tags: recreational-mathematics, poker

We are playing heads-up Texas hold 'em poker. I want to find a situation where my hand is currently weaker than my opponent's (in the sense of hand rank if no more cards were to be drawn), but has the highest possible expectation of being the strongest hand after the river.

The set-up and constraints:

1. There are two players, so no cards have been folded. Ignore any cards that may be burned during the flop, turn, or river.
2. Player A has the highest ranked hand (not in expectation but in absolute rank at the moment).
3. The situation may be at any point in the game - from pre-flop to pre-river.

The goal: Choose the situation (namely the hands of Players A and B and any community cards) so as to maximize the expectation that Player B has the strongest hand post-river.

I have played around with this and have a candidate answer where the expectation of Player B is slightly above 64%. I would welcome the results of a brute force calculation, a better example, or a better example with proof of optimality (I suspect a proof will be tedious...).

Comment: As a bonus, one can consider the relaxation where a small number of burned cards are allowed, which more-or-less captures the scenario of other players who may have folded. For example, can Player B do even better when there are up to 2 burned cards? How about when there are 4, 6, or 8?

Comment: I have found an improvement at just above 70%.

Comment: You said "absolute rank at the moment". In the pre-flop case, would that mean a pair of twos is better than AK offsuit? Do two cards of the same suit count as a flush pre-flop? (Also I don't see how burned cards could affect the probability if they're unknown.)

Comment: Correct. A pair of twos is better than A-K pre-flop. Two cards of the same suit are not a flush; a flush requires 5 cards of the same suit. Yes, when I mention burned cards in the "bonus", I mean that you get to choose the burned cards.

Comment: Pre-flop, it's hard to imagine a better example than a pair of twos vs AK same suit, right?  I wonder what the percentages are for these two hands.

Comment: @antkam In your example, the odds of a win for the A-K player are 49.8%, according to the odds calculator at cardplayer.com. I too would think that this is the best pre-flop; the examples mentioned above are after the flop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Played around at https://www.cardplayer.com/poker-tools/odds-calculator/texas-holdem a bit.

- Pre-flop: The best cards against a pair of twos is not A-K same suit, but rather something more intermediate to allow more straights.  The best I can find is J-10 same suit (and different suit from the twos).  This has a win chance of $53.28\%$ and tie chance of $1.41\%$.
- Post-flop: The best I can find is also somewhat obvious: a four card straight flush with both ends open.  E.g. C2,D2 vs HK,HQ with the flop being HJ,H10,S6.  This has a win chance of $72.32\%$ (and no chance of tying).

Comment: Great - looks very promising. Are you convinced (as I largely am) that looking at the post-turn case will not yield anything better?

Comment: Oh absolutely.  Post-flop there are two chances for the currently-weaker hand to improve.  Post-turn, the weaker hand has only one chance to improve.